# Why passport-Facebook Strategy never get called

Tags: node.js, next.js, passport-facebook

I use Node.js and Next.js. My redirect get to my client then call get callback API to this code:

```
export const loginCallback = async (ctx) => {

  await passport.authenticate('facebook', { session: false }),
 
    console.log('masuk ga')
    let token, refreshToken;

    const user = await Users.query().where("email", "rizki@mail.com").where("deleted_at", null).execute();

       token = await generateTokenFB(user[0].id, appConfig.secretAccessToken, appConfig.expAccessToken);
       refreshToken = await generateTokenFB(user[0].id, appConfig.secretRefreshToken, appConfig.expRefreshToken);

}
```

I use JWT not session. and the token what I get is, my web token not from facebook.

What is the alternative for save my token from facebook?

here's my app.ts codes:
https://pastebin.com/2JJxW9dR

I tried everything but it doesn't work.